# Mocking of same type getting overridden in junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

Test case code ->

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AzureTopicPublisherTest {

    @Mock
    @Qualifier("ackPublisherv1")
    AckPublisher ackPublisherv1;

    @Mock
    @Qualifier("ackPublisherv2")
    AckPublisher ackPublisherv2;
```

Source code ->

```
private final AckPublisher ackPublisherv1;

private final AckPublisher ackPublisherv2;  

public void test()
{
        ackPublisherv1.publishToTopic(response);
        ackPublisherv2.publishToTopic(response);
}
```

Mocks which are not working ->

```
 verify(ackPublisherv1, times(1)).publishToTopic(anyString());
 verify(ackPublisherv2, times(1)).publishToTopic(anyString());
```

Issue is I observed one of the instance getting called twice.
There is different mock for ackPublisherv1 and ackPublisherv2
when i debug this code then i can see same instance twice in source code.

if I write above mock as follows then its working but that is not expected behavior ->

```
 verify(ackPublisherv2, times(2)).publishToTopic(anyString());
```

I tried removing qualifier annotations as well. still same error.

Comment: please refer https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know @InjectMocks doesn't support @Qualifiers.
Instantiate the class you have the `test` method in a setup method.

```java
    @Mock
    AckPublisher ackPublisherv1;

    @Mock
    AckPublisher ackPublisherv2;

    SourceClass underTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        underTest = new SourceClass(ackPublisherv1, ackPublisherv2);
    }
```